# Spring Boot Quarts - send misfires to rabbitmq

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I am looking for a way to listen for/identify misfires with Quartz.  Basically if an job fails to execute, how can I send it to a queue, so it can be processed later?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I can listen for misfires.  http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/cookbook/TriggerListeners.html